# Get rid of spaces after search

Tags: javascript, php, html, input

I've just created a small search engine.. It works fine, but, whenever I search something up with a space on the end; it shows all contents that are in the database? How do I make it so that when people have a space at the end of their input field, it doesn't include that space. Thanks :)

Comment: Trim the input first?

Answer (score 2):

Use `trim` on the filter input.

Php: http://php.net/trim

or

Javascript: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use [trim()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) to trim spaces.

```
 str.trim() //Where str is the value of search field
```